# How do drop rows of a matrix, depending on different matrix with the same dimensions in r?

Tags: r, matrix

I have to matrices `a` and `b` with the same dimension. I would like to drop all the rows in `a` and `b`, where a condition in `a` is not met.

**Minimal example:**

I would like to only keep rows, where the last element of the row is equal to 4 in `a`:

```
a
 [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4

b
 [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    7    7
[2,]    8    8    8

a[a[,3] == 4,]
[1]    2    3    4

# do stuff, so I am also only left with 
b 
[1]    8    8    8
```

What would be a smart way to do this?

Comment: `b[a[,3] == 4,]; a[a[,3] == 4,]`

Comment: `a[a[,1] == 4,]` results in an empty matrix.. unlike in your example...

Comment: @snoram You are right. It is supposed to be `a[a[,3] == 4]`

Comment: @Thomas Thank you! That was the solution. I should have thought of that myself. Pls write this as the answer so I can mark this question as resolved

Comment: For speed/transparency: you can start by defining `rows <- a[,3] == 4` and then do `b[rows, ]; a[rows, ]`

Comment: @snoram Sounds like a good solution, too. Thaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the objects are the same dimensions, then logical indices for `a` will also work for `b`:

```
a[a[,3] == 4,]
b[a[,3] == 4,]
```

If they have different numbers of rows, then this will recycle (with a warning).